# How to shuffle one column of a dataframe based on a row value in R?

Tags: r

I have a sports dataset that reads as follows:

```
season  team   tm  region 
2015    sharks shk  north
2015    dogs   dgs  south
2015    bears  brs  south
2015    cats   cts  north
2015    cows   cws  north
2014    sharks shk  north
2014    dogs   dgs  south
2014    bears  brs  south
2014    cats   cts  north
2014    cows   cws  north
```

I want to shuffle the region column, which I know how to do. However, for each year (2015 and 2014), there should be 3 "north" and 2 "south". In addition, I want 2015 and 2014 to have the same random region for a specific team. So, 2015 sharks and 2014 sharks should have the same region even after being randomized. This is an example of how the randomization might look:

```
season  team   tm  region 
2015    sharks shk  south
2015    dogs   dgs  south
2015    bears  brs  north
2015    cats   cts  north
2015    cows   cws  north
2014    sharks shk  south
2014    dogs   dgs  south
2014    bears  brs  north
2014    cats   cts  north
2014    cows   cws  north
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do in the next way

```
    data = data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            season = c(2015L,2015L,2015L,2015L,
                       2015L,2014L,2014L,2014L,2014L,2014L),
              team = c("sharks","dogs","bears",
                       "cats","cows","sharks","dogs","bears","cats","cows"),
                tm = c("shk","dgs","brs","cts",
                       "cws","shk","dgs","brs","cts","cws"),
            region = c("north","south","south",
                       "north","north","north","south","south","north","north")
)
head(data)

north_south = sample(c("north", "south"), 5, prob = c(0.6, 0.4), replace = T)

data2 = data.frame(data, Region2 = rep(north_south, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the restriction that the region should be replicated in each year, this problem reduces to randomly assigning each team a region and then replicating this assignment throughout the rest of your data frame.

Let's start with a toy data set that has three teams (I drop sharks and bears here to make the example a bit smaller).

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  season = c(rep(2015, 3), rep(2014, 3)),
  team = c("dogs", "cats", "cows", "dogs", "cats", "cows"),
  tm = c("dgs", "cts", "cws", "dgs", "cts", "cows")
)
df1
#>   season team   tm
#> 1   2015 dogs  dgs
#> 2   2015 cats  cts
#> 3   2015 cows  cws
#> 4   2014 dogs  dgs
#> 5   2014 cats  cts
#> 6   2014 cows cows
```

Now we can make a data frame that contains the distinct teams:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(
  team = c("dogs", "cats", "cows")
)
df2
#>   team
#> 1 dogs
#> 2 cats
#> 3 cows
```

We can add a variable to `df2` called `region`, which must have two values randomly equal `"north"` and one value randomly equal `"south"` (your example calls for three and two, respectively). We do this using `$` assignment (a tidyverse equivalent using dplyr would be `mutate()`):

```r
df2$region <- sample(c("north", "north", "south"))
df2
#>   team region
#> 1 dogs  north
#> 2 cats  south
#> 3 cows  north
```

The last step is to link `df2` back up with `df1` using `merge()` (a tidyverse equivalent using dplyr would be `left_join()`):

```
df <- merge(df1, df2)
df
#>   team season   tm region
#> 1 cats   2015  cts  south
#> 2 cats   2014  cts  south
#> 3 cows   2015  cws  north
#> 4 cows   2014 cows  north
#> 5 dogs   2015  dgs  north
#> 6 dogs   2014  dgs  north
```

Note that `merge()` here reorders your rows and columns, whereas `dplyr::left_join()` preserves the row and column order of the first argument:

```r
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2)
#> Joining, by = "team"
#>   season team   tm region
#> 1   2015 dogs  dgs  north
#> 2   2015 cats  cts  south
#> 3   2015 cows  cws  north
#> 4   2014 dogs  dgs  north
#> 5   2014 cats  cts  south
#> 6   2014 cows cows  north
```

For more on joins with a focus on the tidyverse approach (`dplyr::left_join()` and others), see [this link](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @yoyoman32, if you thought the answer was correct, please mark it as correct and / or upvote it so others will be more likely to read through it  find help from it -- thanks!